# How can i add text label on image in custom tableviewcell in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi everybody , 
           I am new in iOS development.Now i am working on custom tableView, in this i am using custom tableViewCell. On that cell  i am adding text label on imageView. But its not showing text label on image view. only image showing. 
   If anybody have any solution on this problem please help me.

here is my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    ItemsCellVC *cell = (ItemsCellVC *)[TableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ItemsCellVC alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    }

    UIImage *background = [self cellBackgroundForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *cellBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:background];
    cellBackgroundView.image = background;
    cell.backgroundView = cellBackgroundView;





    if ([arrayForItemDictionary count]!=0) {

    if (tableView == aSearchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
      {
        dictItemFromDatabase=[filteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      }
    else
       {
        dictItemFromDatabase=[arrayForItemDictionary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       }

   }




    //cell.containerNameLabel.text=[dictItemFromDatabase valueForKey:@"PickerName"];
    cell.itemNameLabel.text = [dictItemFromDatabase valueForKey:@"ItemNameTF"];
    cell.containerImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"12-02 (1)"];

  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2-02 (1).png"];

   cell.containerImgView.image = [self addText:image text:@"Hello there"];



    return cell;
}


-(UIImage *)addText:(UIImage *)img text:(NSString *)text1{

    int w = img.size.width;
    int h = img.size.height;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), img.CGImage);

    char* text= (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial",20, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context,10,10,text, strlen(text));
    CGImageRef imgCombined = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    UIImage *retImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgCombined];
    CGImageRelease(imgCombined);

    return retImage;
}
```

Comment: Add cellforrowatindex code

Comment: The best way is to make a custom cell, with an imageView and a label, and add them to the subview when the cell is initialized.

Then make sure they're hooked up to a property so you can configure the frame, as well as the content.

Comment: but imageview and text label taken in storyboard directly and i did first add imageview and on that add text label but its not working on cell

Comment: Finally i got solution of this question...thank you all of you.

Comment: thank you  Rajat Deep Singh for solving my problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After trying hard then i got this solution:

I had use this method in tableViewCellVC.m file

```
@implementation UIImage (DrawWatermarkText)
-(UIImage*)drawWatermarkText:(NSString*)text {
 UIColor *textColor = [UIColor grayColor];//[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.1];
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:400];
//  CGFloat paddingX = 50.f;
CGFloat paddingY = 200.f;

// Compute rect to draw the text inside
CGSize imageSize = self.size;
NSDictionary *attr = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor, NSFontAttributeName: font};
CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithAttributes:attr];

// CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(imageSize.width - textSize.width - paddingX, imageSize.height - textSize.height - paddingY-50, textSize.width, textSize.height);

CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(imageSize.width - 1900, imageSize.height - textSize.height - paddingY, textSize.width, textSize.height);

// Create the image
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
[self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];
[text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(textRect) withAttributes:attr];
UIImage *resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return resultImage;}@end

later on i had write following code in tableViewCellVC.h file as

@interface UIImage (DrawWatermarkText)
-(UIImage*)drawWatermarkText:(NSString*)text;
  @end
And Finally in cellforRowAtIndexPath in tavelVC.m call this method only

 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"12-02 (1)"];

cell.containerImgView.image  = [image drawWatermarkText:@"Bharat"];
```

Then its works